# How I can Store value of echo into php variable

Tags: javascript, php, echo, ob-start, ob-get-contents

I wanted to store value of a echo into php variable but only i get is the HTML tag not actual value that hold that tag.

**Javascript**

```
function openModal()
{
    var checked=false;
    var elements = document.getElementsByName("offer[]");
    for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
       if(elements[i].checked) 
       {
           ele=elements[i].value;
           alert(ele);
           checked = true;      
       }                        
    }
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=ele;      
}
```

**PHP**

```
ob_start();
echo "<label id='testH1'></label>";
$myStr = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

when i access the $myStr using `'echo "My String ".$myStr;'` it will display the actual value that id hold,but when i pass this $myStr to URL,It will again display `echo "<label id='testH1'></label>"`

I need to pass the value of $myStr to next page via url. How i can do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a redirection with get param, or send it via form and a $_POST.

With get param you can do :

```
$url = 'my_page.php?param=' . urlencode($myStr);
header('Location : ' . $url);
exit();
```

Comment: I wanted to pass url to Anchor tag and your code will give some encoding values that was not recognize by url as the result it will display blank value.  Here is my anchor tag with your solution   <a href='../interviewHr/createfile.php?id='".urlencode($myStr)."'>